# Double increment loop in python

Tags: python, loops, iteration, ipython

I am trying to use a loop that will increment two variables so I can generate a heatmap plot that will reveal the similarity of the files in a simple form.

The idea is if I have 100 files, I would like to compare each of them to one another. Currently I repeat my comparisons (i.e. compare file 1 & 2 and then file 2 & 1) which is very inefficient. The current stripped down script I have is shown below:

```
 for fileX in range(1,4):
    for fileY in range(1,4):
        print "X is " + str(fileX) + ", Y is " + str(fileY)
```

The output I obtain is something like this:

```
X is 1, Y is 1
X is 1, Y is 2
X is 1, Y is 3
X is 2, Y is 1
X is 2, Y is 2
X is 2, Y is 3
X is 3, Y is 1
X is 3, Y is 2
X is 3, Y is 3
```

Whereas what I am looking for is something like this:

```
X is 1, Y is 1 << not necessary since it is always 100 %
X is 1, Y is 2
X is 1, Y is 3
X is 2, Y is 2 << not necessary since it is always 100 %
X is 2, Y is 3
X is 3, Y is 3 << not necessary since it is always 100 %
```

The reason being, I have already compared files 1 & 2, 1 & 3 and 2 & 3 in the previous iteration. Obviously for a short list of a couple files this is not overly bad, however for hundred files it increases the computation significantly. This will enable me to speed up the comparison quite significantly, especially since the files that I am comparing are usually pretty large (~500K lines each).

Comment: `if x == y: continue`? or make a list of previous comparisons and if the comparison is in the list continue

Comment: Please explain what the similarity is.  Char by char? Line by line? Whole content?

Comment: I am doing two separate comparisons. 1) I compare them line by line and output what is the same and what is different. 2) I compare the lists using pd.intercept/pd.difference to give me a number of lines that are the same. Then I convert it to a percentage value which is my score.

Comment: @Pynchia The question is not about similarity so it's irrelevant what "similarity" is.

Comment: Why do you compare 1 to 2 and then 2 to 1. Does is return different results?

Comment: In a way it gives different results but they are just a reverse of one another. So it is not necessary to compute 1 and 2 and then 2 and 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the value of the first loop as the starting value of the range of the second loop like

```
for fileX in range(1,4):
    for fileY in range(fileX,4):
```

To also skip the equall ones do

```
for fileX in range(1,4):
    for fileY in range(fileX+1,4):
```

Comment: That is a smart answer

Comment: Thanks! That works just as I wanted. I knew it was trivial, but didn't consider your answer. I think I should read a bit more about loops/for statements! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel. If you need combinations, just use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
for fileX, fileY in itertools.combinations(range(1,4), 2):
    print "X is " + str(fileX) + ", Y is " + str(fileY)
```

Output:

```
X is 1, Y is 2
X is 1, Y is 3
X is 2, Y is 3
```

Compared to the double-for-loop, this is somewhat more readable (the code tells you exactly what it does) and less prone of introducing silly off-by-one errors and the like. Also, this works equally well with *any* sort of collection or iterable, not just with an ordered list of numbers.

Comment: Beat me to it except I had `print 'X is {}, Y is {}'.format(fileX, fileY)` :)

Comment: @JonClements Agreed, that's better. I just wanted to change the relevant bits, though.